# Manjaro ARM on Raspberry Pi 4 model B cannot connect with Google Nest Audio speakers through Bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, manjaro, bluez

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 4 model B device using the Manjaro ARM KDE plasma OS, to connect with Google Nest Audio speakers through Bluetooth. Connection through the KDE GUI 'Bluedevil'-application fails, cfr.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHvJs.jpg)

To further explore the issue I tried to setup it up using the more reliable CLI interface, namely using the bluetoothctl utility as described on the Arch wiki: [Arch wiki CLI bluetooth pairing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Pairing). However this process fails as well on the very last step to run the 'connect'-command. Notice all of the following steps have been taken into account:

```
- Installing bluez, bluez-utils packages
- Loading the kernel module 'btusb' (was not yet loaded)
- Starting the bluetooth.service
- Adding the user to the 'lp' group
- The 'default-agent' was used
- The MAC-adress of the Google Nest speakers was trusted using 'trust'-command
```

The pairing did work, but the following output keeps rapidly filling the screen when connecting [Connect-command output](https://pastebin.com/88UwnXjg?fbclid=IwAR3bys_fewvq0gFo2Ar8qfNzYp0EElVgD266mpOG0Jw9GZLd8gD1NZm-aDM).

At some point during testing and fiddling around I also checked the logging in the journal: [Journal logging](https://pastebin.com/k6sa7DYv). Most remarkable seems to be line 74 with an error message containing the MAC-address of the speakers:

> src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed
> for 14:C1:4E:D1:96:AB: Device or resource busy

In a desperate attempt to get more logging I tried to follow the debugging activation steps in the  Arch wiki: [Arch wiki debugging](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Debugging). However the following command:

> sudo /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -n -d

failed with the error message [Debugging command output](https://pastebin.com/z9QLLUg4).

Other information that might be usefull:

```
- OS: 'Manjaro Raspberry Pi 4 KDE Plasma 21.06 (ARM)'

- Kernel version: '5.10.43-1-MANJARO-ARM #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 14 14:31:41 UTC 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux'
- PipeWire version: 1:0.3.30+85+ga168e4261-1. According to [Arch wiki Bluetooth audio section][7] this version should enable its Bluetooth support by default.
- Same setup has been tested on 'Manjaro Raspberry Pi 4 XFCE 21.06 (ARM)' through the GUI 'Blueman'-application. Connection also failed.
- All packages were updated before setup using the command 'sudo pacman -Syu'
```

Remark: Even though the GUI connection failed, a new Bluetooth device was added in the KDE system settings for Bluetooth. This as a side note as no audio device was shown in the audio settings and no audio could be played.